# How to correctly open and query database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have my nextQuestion method which I call every time I need new question to ask in my game, using imported sqlite prepopulated database. I think I did it wrong cause every time I ask new question my database gets created again. But I tried to place the db stuff in activity scope but I get error mDbHelper.createDatabase(); line (Syntax error on token createDatabase, indetifier expected after this token). Here's my nextQuestion method, which I call first time in onCreate method and after that after each user answer.

```
public void nextQuestion() {

        TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();

        try{

            mDbHelper.open();  //baza otvorena

            Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestData(generateWhereClause());
            mAnsweredQuestions.add(c.getLong(0));

            List<Answer> labels = new ArrayList<Answer>();

            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(2), true));
            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(3), false));
            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(4), false));
            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(5), false));

            Collections.shuffle(labels);

            tacanOdg = c.getString(2);


        question.setText(c.getString(1));

        bOdgovor1.setText(labels.get(0).option);
        bOdgovor1.setTag(labels.get(0));
        bOdgovor1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        bOdgovor2.setText(labels.get(1).option);
        bOdgovor2.setTag(labels.get(1));
        bOdgovor2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        bOdgovor3.setText(labels.get(2).option);
        bOdgovor3.setTag(labels.get(2));
        bOdgovor3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        bOdgovor4.setText(labels.get(3).option);
        bOdgovor4.setTag(labels.get(3));
        bOdgovor4.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            }
```

How to do this correctly?

Here's my Helper if needed.

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window
//destination path (location) of our database on device
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture/databases/"; 
private static String DB_NAME ="pitanja.sqlite";// Database name
private static SQLiteDatabase mDataBase; 
private final Context mContext;
private static final String KEY_ID = "_ID";
private static final String KEY_PITANJE = "PITANJE";
private static final String KEY_ODGOVOR = "ODGOVOR";
private static final String KEY_OPCIJA1 = "OPCIJA1";
private static final String KEY_OPCIJA2 = "OPCIJA2";
private static final String KEY_OPCIJA3 = "OPCIJA3";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tblPitanja";

public DataBaseHelper(Context mojContext) 
{
    super(mojContext, DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? its Database Version
    DB_PATH = mojContext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    this.mContext = mojContext;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException
{
    //If database not exists copy it from the assets


        this.getReadableDatabase();
        this.close();
        try 
        {
            //Copy the database from assests
            copyDataBase();
            Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
        } 
        catch (IOException mIOException) 
        {
            throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
        }
    }
    /*Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Da Name
    private boolean checkDataBase()
    {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
        return dbFile.exists();
    }
    */

    //Copy the database from assets
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
        {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }

    //Open the database, so we can query it
    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException
    {
        String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        //Log.v("mPath", mPath);
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        //mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        return mDataBase != null;
    }

    public void close() 
    {
        if(mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }


    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        }


    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        Log.w("DataBaseHelper", "Upgrading database!!!!!");
          onCreate(arg0);

    }

}
```

and TestAdapter:

```
public class TestAdapter 
{
    protected static final String TAG = "DataAdapter";

    private final Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;

    public TestAdapter(Context context) 
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);
    }

    public TestAdapter createDatabase() throws SQLException 
    {
        try 
        {
            mDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } 
        catch (IOException mIOException) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString() + "  UnableToCreateDatabase");
            throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase");
        }
        return this;
    }

    public TestAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        try 
        {
            mDbHelper.openDataBase();
            mDbHelper.close();
            mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        } 
        catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "open >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
            throw mSQLException;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void close() 
    {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

     public Cursor getTestData(String whereClause)
     {;
         try
         {
             String sql ="SELECT * FROM tblPitanja WHERE 1 = 1 " + whereClause + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";

             Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
             if (mCur!=null)
             {
                mCur.moveToNext();
             }
             return mCur;
         }
         catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
         {
             Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
             throw mSQLException;
         }
     }
}
```

OK, i've edited my database helper class and added this code to check if db exists:

```
**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
public boolean checkDataBase(){

SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

try{
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}catch(SQLiteException e){

//database does't exist yet.

}

if(checkDB != null){

checkDB.close();

}

return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}
```

Then in my game activity I check if this method return true or false, and if it's false I create db:

```
TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        if(!myDbHelper.checkDataBase()){
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();
        }

        try{

            mDbHelper.open();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu should not call `createDatabase()` all the time but put DB creation in helper's `onCreate()`. And you shall also `close()` your db (`mDbHelper.close()`) when done.

EDIT: you seem to want to init your DB based on sqlite file stored in assets? If so, instead of reinventing the wheel use this helper: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: Can you tell me which lines to place in onCreate method? And what do you mean by "helper's onCreate"? I don't have onCreate method in my DBHelper class.

Comment: And also when I put createDatabase() in my onCreate() method, I get errors in my nextQuestion() method cause mDbHelper.open(); cause createDatabase() is in different scope.

Comment: Assuming your TestAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper, there is a SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) method you can override. That is where you should put your table creation statements.

Comment: What I've done is deleted the mDbHelper.createDatabase(); Is that OK? Now my db does not get created after each question.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up your SQLiteHelper class like the one provided in the link.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial_database

Then after that in the tutorial is a CommentsDataSource class, which is equivalent to your TestAdapter class.

Comment: Yes but this is creating new database, and I have database imported in Assets folder. I just need to know what is the right way to create and open my database upon creation of my activity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the good example of DataBaseHelper that you can use:

> ```
> public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
>
> //The Android's default system path of your application database.
> private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/";
>
> private static String DB_NAME = "myDBName";
>
> private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
>
> private final Context myContext;
>
> /**
>   * Constructor
>   * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
>   * @param context
>   */
> public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
>
> super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
> this.myContext = context;
> } 
>
> /**
>   * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
>   * */
> public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
>
> boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
>
> if(dbExist){
> //do nothing - database already exist
> }else{
>
> //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
> //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
> this.getReadableDatabase();
>
> try {
>
> copyDataBase();
>
> } catch (IOException e) {
>
> throw new Error("Error copying database");
>
> }
> }
>
> }
>
> /**
>   * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
>   * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
>   */
> private boolean checkDataBase(){
>
> SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
>
> try{
> String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
> checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
>
> }catch(SQLiteException e){
>
> //database does't exist yet.
>
> }
>
> if(checkDB != null){
>
> checkDB.close();
>
> }
>
> return checkDB != null ? true : false;
> }
>
> /**
>   * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
>   * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
>   * This is done by transfering bytestream.
>   * */
> private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
>
> //Open your local db as the input stream
> InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
>
> // Path to the just created empty db
> String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
>
> //Open the empty db as the output stream
> OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
>
> //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
> byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
> int length;
> while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
> myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
> }
>
> //Close the streams
> myOutput.flush();
> myOutput.close();
> myInput.close();
>
> }
>
> public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
>
> //Open the database
> String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
> myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
>
> }
>
> @Override
> public synchronized void close() {
>
> if(myDataBase != null)
> myDataBase.close();
>
> super.close();
>
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
>
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
>
> }
>
> // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
> // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
> // to you to create adapters for your views.
>
> }
> ```

and after that to open database:

```
 ...

DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper();
myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

try {

myDbHelper.createDataBase();

} catch (IOException ioe) {

throw new Error("Unable to create database");

}

try {

myDbHelper.openDataBase();

}catch(SQLException sqle){

throw sqle;

}

...
```

Comment: Yes, good example, but my adaper and dbHelper are pretty much the same. I only need to know what to do in my game activity, how to safely open and close db. I think now i've managed to do that by deleting the mDbHelper.createDatabase(); line.

Comment: By deleting the mDbHelper.createDatabase() it works only for now, because you use only openDataBase() method. If you will delete your application and then re-install it you will need mDbHelper.createDatabase() again.

Comment: I guess you're right. Is there a way to correct my code to avoid this? I'd rather do that then using another database helper code.

Comment: What you definitely need to do is to make the code like above, first you need to try to create database and then to open it. In your code I don't really understand why do you need TestAdapter class. But anyway, as I see in method open(), first you try to open database and then you close it. Try to remove this to lines:mDbHelper.close(); mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase(); And also, if you need your nextQuestion() method to call a few times, then you don't need to try to open database everytime you call nextQuestion(). You can open database before using this method and then just use it.

Comment: In open() method you execute this:            mDbHelper.openDataBase();
mDbHelper.close();
mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase(); Your database helper is wrong and I don't really understand why you need TestAdapter class. After you do this: mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY); you need to work with database mDataBase and perform queries with it. I advise you to use this helper that I wrote above, it will be much easier.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27792/discussion-between-yyunikov-and-marjanbaz)